# No C# tem alguma classe para manipulação de arquivos properties?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, configuração

No C# tem alguma classe para manipulação de [arquivos `properties`](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-arquivos-de-propriedades-no-java/25546)? Em Java eu utilizo a classe `Properties`, queria saber se tem uma equivalente em C#?

Comment: O que essa classe faz no Java? Cite exemplos

Comment: Que tipo de arquivo é este?

Comment: Este artigo explica os arquivos properties no java http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-arquivos-de-propriedades-no-java/25546 e queria saber se tem no c#

Comment: @viniciusafx acho q vc terá que fazer seu próprio arquivo ini para guarda dados de configuração. Não encontrei suporte em C# para manipular este tipo de arquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem algumas bibliotecas que permitem fazer algo bem sofisticado. Não saberia indicar uma específica.

Tem alguma coisa um pouco diferente na biblioteca padrão, seria a classe [`ConfigurationManager`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Tem uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696370/221800) com um exemplo tentando reproduzir a base desta classe em C#.

Comment: Enquanto eu estava aguardando respostas aqui, eu resolvi criar um projeto para resolver isto, e quando terminei vi que estava muito parecido com o exemplo que você citou, mas que fique claro que eu não copiei. Link do meu projeto: https://github.com/viniciusafx/Properties/blob/master/Properties/Properties.cs

Comment: Pra mim seria indiferente se tivesse copiado. Fico contente que está no caminho que deseja.

Answer (score 4):

Sou leigo em Java, mas acredito que esta falando de guardar informações de "configuração" e/ou informações diversas em um local para serem "consumidas" quando necessário.

No C# existem algumas formas de se fazer isso, porém a mais correta é:

**Aplicações Web:** Arquivo `Web.config`

> O web.config é um arquivo especial, semelhante ao .htaccess utilizado pelo Apache, que configura o comportamento de sua aplicação. Criado com o formato XML podendo ser editado facilmente com um editor comum, como o bloco de notas.
>
> O web.config, geralmente é utilizado para armazenar valores e parâmetros que sejam comuns em toda aplicação.
>
> No entanto, cada aplicação Web criada pode ter seu próprio arquivo web.config, e as informações deste arquivo valem para o diretório corrente e seus subdiretórios.
>
> [fonte](http://wiki.infolink.com.br/Web.config)

Existe uma "seção" dentro do `Web.config` chamada `appSettings` que é utilizada para "guardarmos" informações que podem ser "acessadas" posteriormente.

**Ex.:**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NomeSistema" value="Meu sistema" />
    <add key="UrlLocalhost" value="http://localhost" />
    <add key="UrlSite" value="http://meusite.com.br" />
    <add key="defaultCulture" value="pt-BR" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Se necessário adicione a referencia assembly:**

```
using System.Configuration;
```

**Para acessar os dados:**

```
label.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NomeSistema"];
```

---

**Aplicações Desktop:** Arquivo `App.config`

Mesma coisa que na aplicação Web:

**Ex.:**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NomeSistema" value="Meu sistema" />
    <add key="UrlLocalhost" value="http://localhost" />
    <add key="UrlSite" value="http://meusite.com.br" />
    <add key="defaultCulture" value="pt-BR" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Se necessário adicione a referencia assembly:**

```
using System.Configuration;
```

**Para acessar os dados:**

```
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NomeSistema"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muitas dores, encontrei esse artigo no VOL... falando da LibConfuse: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Criando-programas-com-suporte-a-arquivos-de-configuracao-com-a-libConfuse

Estou estudando pois tenho um problema bem parecido e, ate agora ela passou nos meus testes...  sem contar que eh muito fácil de usar.

**MAS como nao acabei de testar** não tenho certeza se tem versão para C#.